# How quickly can Realm return sorted data?

Tags: realm, mongodb-realm

Realm allows you to receive the results of a query in sorted order.

```swift
let realm = try! Realm()
let dogs = realm.objects(Dog.self)
let dogsSorted = dogs.sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: false)
```

I ran this test to see how quickly realm returns sorted data

```swift
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class TestModel: Object {
    @Persisted(indexed: true) var value: Int = 0
}

class RealmSortTest {
    let documentCount = 1000000
    var smallestValue: TestModel = TestModel()
    
    func writeData() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        var documents: [TestModel] = []
        for _ in 0 ... documentCount {
            let newDoc = TestModel()
            newDoc.value = Int.random(in: 0 ... Int.max)
            documents.append(newDoc)
        }
        try! realm.write {
            realm.deleteAll()
            realm.add(documents)
        }
    }
    
    func readData() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let sortedResults = realm.objects(TestModel.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "value")
                
        let start = Date()
        
        self.smallestValue = sortedResults[0]
        
        let end = Date()
        let delta = end.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - start.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        print("Time Taken: \(delta)")
    }
    
    func updateSmallestValue() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let sortedResults = realm.objects(TestModel.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "value")

        smallestValue = sortedResults[0]
        
        print("Originally loaded smallest value: \(smallestValue.value)")
        
        let newSmallestValue = TestModel()
        newSmallestValue.value = smallestValue.value - 1
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(newSmallestValue)
        }
        
        print("Originally loaded smallest value after write: \(smallestValue.value)")
        
        let readStart = Date()
        smallestValue = sortedResults[0]
        let readEnd = Date()
        let readDelta = readEnd.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - readStart.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        print("Reloaded smallest value \(smallestValue.value)")
        print("Time Taken to reload the smallest value: \(readDelta)")
    }
}
```

With `documentCount = 100000`, readData() output:

```
Time taken to load smallest value: 0.48901796340942383
```

and updateData() output:

```
Originally loaded smallest value: 2075613243102
Originally loaded smallest value after write: 2075613243102
Reloaded smallest value 2075613243101
Time taken to reload the smallest value: 0.4624580144882202
```

With `documentCount = 1000000`, readData() output:

```
Time taken to load smallest value: 4.807577967643738
```

and updateData() output:

```
Originally loaded smallest value: 4004790407680
Originally loaded smallest value after write: 4004790407680
Reloaded smallest value 4004790407679
Time taken to reload the smallest value: 5.2308430671691895
```

The time taken to retrieve the first document from a sorted result set is scaling with the number of documents stored in realm rather than the number of documents being retrieved. This indicates to me that realm is sorting all of the documents at query time rather than when the documents are being written. Is there a way to index your data so that you can quickly retrieve a small number of sorted documents?

**Edit:**

Following discussion in the comments, I updated the code to load only the smallest value from the sorted collection.

**Edit 2**

I updated the code to `observe` the results as suggested in the comments.

```swift
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class TestModel: Object {
    @Persisted(indexed: true) var value: Int = 0
}

class RealmSortTest {
    let documentCount = 1000000
    var smallestValue: TestModel = TestModel()
    var storedResults: Results<TestModel> = (try! Realm()).objects(TestModel.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "value")
    var resultsToken: NotificationToken? = nil
    
    func writeData() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        var documents: [TestModel] = []
        for _ in 0 ... documentCount {
            let newDoc = TestModel()
            newDoc.value = Int.random(in: 0 ... Int.max)
            documents.append(newDoc)
        }
        try! realm.write {
            realm.deleteAll()
            realm.add(documents)
        }
    }
    
    func observeData() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        print("Loading Data")
        let startTime = Date()
        self.storedResults = realm.objects(TestModel.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "value")
        self.resultsToken = self.storedResults.observe { changes in
            let observationTime = Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)
            print("Time to first observation: \(observationTime)")
            let firstTenElementsSlice = self.storedResults[0..<10]
            let elementsArray = Array(firstTenElementsSlice) //print this if you want to see the elements
            elementsArray.forEach { print($0.value) }
            let moreElapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)
            print("Time to printed elements: \(moreElapsed)")
        }
    }
}
```

and I got the following output

```
Loading Data
Time to first observation: 5.252112984657288
3792614823099
56006949537408
Time to printed elements: 5.253015995025635
```

Reading the data with an observer did not reduce the time taken to read the data.

Comment: For clarification, the code in the question is not related to how fast objects are loaded from Realm. e.g. appending objects to an array doesn't have anything to do with Realm; and it seems only 10 elements `let readCount = 10`. Most importantly, the code takes the super-quick lazily-loading Realm objects and casts them to memory gobbling objects, loading them into memory which by nature will vary depending on size. A true test would be to load the objects into a Results object that has an observer, and compare the time start against when the observer event fires (when loading is done).

Comment: @Jay Sorry Jay, but I think your wrong here. Your comment above is misleading. In this code, adding the realm objects to an array just forces their values to be loaded (as if they were being used in a view). All memory allocation was handled before the timer started, so that is not a factor in the test. The only variable I changed between runs of the test is the total number of documents stored in Realm. When 100,000 documents were stored in Realm, retrieving 10 sorted values took 0.39 seconds. When 1,000,000 documents were stored in Realm, retrieving 10 sorted values took 4.1 seconds.

Comment: Also, note that I am only timing the section of code where the 10 values are read (the last 7 lines of the function). I specifically do not include the time taken to generate and write the initial documents in the test.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying - however, that's not how to work with Realm. Let me explain. This is the problem **adding the realm objects to an array just forces their values**. That's rarely necessary and really the core of the issue. Realm objects are design to be worked with in a Realm way that maintains their lazy-loading ability; doing anything else defeats that and causes, for example memory and loading issues. **as if they were being used in a view** no, don't do that. Use a *Collection* object in your views (Results, List).

Comment: Your test would perform the same regardless of the database used. The more data in memory, the longer it takes to access that data. Whether you use Realm, Firebase, MySQL or really anything, taking a set of data and casting it to an array will always be the same result; the larger the dataset, the slower it goes. The advantage of Realm over the others is that objects are not loaded *until they are needed*; in comparison to Firebase for example; if you have 100,000 nodes in Firebase you'd have to load 100,000 nodes of data and store them in your array, overwhelming the device.

Comment: As a side use case note: one of our projects has literally gigabytes of data. While it takes a while to combine and write out all of that data, *retrieving* data, sorted in a variety of ways is instantaneous, and we have multiple users banging on that data sorting, reading, editing and writing it all day. The key to making that work is to use Realm data in a Realm way - leverage the lazy-loading abilities and avoid things like casting to in-memory arrays. We use Collections almost exclusively and rarely use Swift arrays.

Comment: So are you saying that the line of code "sortedDocuments.append(sortedQuery[i])" does not just retrieve the ith value of the result but instead forces all values in the result to be loaded? If so, how should you access individual documents from a result set so that the entire result is not automatically loaded? Specifically, if you wanted to only get the first (smallest) value from the sorted set without loading any of the other values, how would you do that?

Comment: Great question and my updated answer (after the Edit) does exactly that. If you wanted the smallest value (in my example) it would be `let smallestValue = self.results[0] //this only accesses element 0`. Keeping in mind that the `results` object will maintain it's sort; so if a smaller value is added for example, the next time `let smallestValue` is called, it will retrieve the new smallest value - without having to re-sort or event re-filter! Cool stuff.

Comment: I did not see the code you were describing in your answer, so I updated the question code. I am not seeing the performance that you describe. Whether I am loading the smallest value for the first time or reloading it after an update, the read time scales directly with the number of documents in Realm.

Comment: See the code after the EDIT. Note this line `self.modelResults = realm.objects(TestModel.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "value")` which populates the `self.modelResults` object with sorted Realm data (per your question). At some point after that, if you want to access an individual document (per your comment above), you would do `let smallestValue = self.modelResults[0]` per my above comment. The code is not describing any performance - it's actually measures and shows the performance based on 10,000 values and then 1,000,000 values. You will see the same performance if you copy and paste that code.

Comment: The key issue here is that when I access the value with something like ```let smallestValue = self.modelResults[0]``` there is a 5 second delay before the value is returned (see the updated code in the question). That delay scales with the number of documents in Realm. Can you provide a code sample where you actually retrieve the smallest value and do something with it (eg. print the value), without that delay?

Comment: Of course! See Edit 2 section of question. The code does the same as before and outputs when accessing 1,000,000 objects is completed (took 0.673, about the same as before). Then it outputs the first 10 values and prints when that completed (completed at 0.674) which means the time to retrieve the data and output it to console was .674 - .673 = .001

Comment: I am not getting the result you describe. See Edit 2 in the question.

Comment: I copy and pasted your updated code, right from the question, with the following results **Time to first observation: 0.6411440372467041** and then **Time to printed elements: 0.6419720649719238**. To verify, I went to a totally different Mac (a MBP 15.4"), created a brand new Realm project and copy and pasted your code there and got pretty much the same results. That indicates you have something else causing your delay issue. Possibly code outside what you've included or maybe even a hardware issue.

Comment: Our results may be more consistent than they appear at first glance. I am running my code on an iPhone SE, which may explain why I am getting a longer access time. When I perform the read with 10000, 100000, and 1000000 documents, I get **Time to first observation** of 0.08423399925231934, 0.5396630764007568, and 5.225836992263794 respectively. This indicates that the time taken to access the first value in the sorted set is scaling roughly linearly with the number of documents in the set. This scaling is what I care about. Do you observe similar scaling when you run the code?

Comment: As a follow up; I had a lengthy conversation with Realm engineers and while your results are possible, it really seems like there's something else at work. For additional testing, I built an iOS app using identical code in my answer and while the results were longer than the macOS app, it was nothing like 5 seconds. My suggestion is a test: build a clean macOS app using the code in my answer and see what the results are. Shouldn't take more than 10 minutes for that exercise. Once you have those results, build a clean iOS app and try it. Those tests will establish a performance base-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time it appears that Realm sorts data when it is accessed rather than when it is written, and there is not a way to have Realm sort data at write time. This means that accessing sorted data scales with the number of documents in the database rather than the number of documents being accessed.

The actual time taken to access the data varies by use case and platform.

Answer (score 0):

`dogs` and `dogsSorted` are Realm [Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Structs/Results.html) Collection object that essentially contains pointers to the underlying data, not the data itself.

Defining a sort order does NOT load all of the objects and they remain lazy - only loading as needed, which is one of the huge benefits to Realm; giant datasets can be used without worrying about overloading memory.

It's also one of the reasons that Realm Results objects always reflect the current state of the data of the underlying data; that data can change many times and what you see in your app Results vars (and [Realm Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Protocols/RealmCollection.html) in general) will always show the updated data.

As a side node, at this time working with Realm Collection objects with Swift High Level functions causes that data to load into memory - so don't do that. Sort, Filter etc with Realm functions and everything stays lazy and memory friendly.

Indexing is a trade off; on one hand it can improve the performance of certain queries like an equality ( "name == 'Spot'" ) but on the other hand it can slow down write performance. Additionally, adding indexes takes up a bit more space.

Generally speaking, indexing is best for specific use cases; maybe in a situation were you doing some kind of type ahead autofill where performance is critical. We have several apps with very large datasets (Gb's) and nothing is indexed because the performance advantage received is offset by slower writes, which are done frequently. I suggest starting without indexing.

**EDIT:**

Going to update the answer based on additional discussion.

First and foremost, copying data from one object to another is not a measure of database loading performance. The real objective here is the user experience and/or being able to access that data - from the time the user expects to see the data to when it's shown. So let's provide some code to demonstrate general performance:

We'll first start with a similar model to what the OP used

```
class TestModel: Object {
    @Persisted(indexed: true) var value: Int = 0
    
    convenience init(withIndex: Int) {
        self.init()
        self.value = withIndex
    }
}
```

Then define a couple of vars to hold the Results from disk and a notification token which allows us to know when that data is available to be displayed to the user. And then lastly a var to hold the time of when the loading starts

```
var modelResults: Results<TestModel>!
var modelsToken: NotificationToken?
var startTime = Date()
```

Here's the function that writes lots of data. The `objectCount` var will be changed from 10,000 objects on the first run to 1,000,000 objects on the second. Note this is bad coding as I am creating a million objects in memory so don't do this; for demonstration purposes only.

```
func writeLotsOfData() {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let objectCount = 1000000
    autoreleasepool {
        var testModelArray = [TestModel]()
        for _ in 0..<objectCount {
            let m = TestModel(withIndex: Int.random(in: 0 ... Int.max))
            testModelArray.append(m)
        }

        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(testModelArray)
        }
        
        print("data written: \(testModelArray.count) objects")
    }
}
```

and then finally the function that loads those objects from realm and outputs when the data is available to be shown to the user. Note they are sorted per the original question - and in fact will maintain their sort as data is added and changed! Pretty cool stuff.

```
func loadBigData() {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    print("Loading Data")
    
    self.startTime = Date()
    self.modelResults = realm.objects(TestModel.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "value")
    self.modelsToken = self.modelResults?.observe { changes in
        let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(self.startTime)
        print("Load completed of \(self.modelResults.count) objects -  elapsed time of \(elapsed)")
    }
}
```

and the results. Two runs, one with 10,000 objects and one with 1,000,000 objects

```
data written: 10000 objects
Loading Data
Load completed of 10000 objects -  elapsed time of 0.0059670209884643555

data written: 1000000 objects
Loading Data
Load completed of 1000000 objects -  elapsed time of 0.6800119876861572
```

There are three things to note

> 1. A Realm Notification object fires an event when the data has
>    completed loading, and also when there are additional changes. We are
>    leveraging that to notify the app when the data has completed loading
>    and is available to be used - shown to the user for example.
> 2. We are lazily loading all of the objects! At no point are we going
>    to run into a memory overloading issue. Once the objects have loaded
>    into the results, they are then freely available to be shown to the
>    user or processed in whatever way is needed. Super important to work
>    with Realm objects in a Realm way when working with large datasets.
>    Generally speaking, if it's 10 objects well, no problem tossing
>    them into an array, but when there are 1 Million objects - let Realm
>    do it's lazy job.
> 3. The app is protected using the above code and techniques. There
>    could be 10 objects or 1,000,000 objects and the memory impact is
>    minimal.

**EDIT 2**

(see comment to the OP's question for more info about this edit)

Per a request fromt the OP, they wanted to see the same exercise with printed values and times. Here's the updated code

```
self.modelsToken = self.modelResults?.observe { changes in
    let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(self.startTime)
    print("Load completed of \(self.modelResults.count) objects -  elapsed time of \(elapsed)")
    print("print first 10 object values")
    let firstTenElementsSlice = self.modelResults[0..<10]
    let elementsArray = Array(firstTenElementsSlice) //print this if you want to see the elements
    elementsArray.forEach { print($0.value)}
    let moreElapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(self.startTime)
    print("Printing of 10 elements completed: \(moreElapsed)")
}
```

and then the output

```
Loading Data
Load completed of 1000000 objects -  elapsed time of 0.6730009317398071
print first 10 object values
12264243738520
17242140785413
29611477414437
31558144830373
32913160803785
45399774467128
61700529799916
63929929449365
73833938586206
81739195218861
Printing of 10 elements completed: 0.6745189428329468
```

Comment: Got it. Does indexing the sorted property (in this case "name") improve the efficiency of the query when requesting sorted results?

Comment: @pdiffley I ran out of time earlier to address Indexing in my answer so it's now been updated.

Comment: I ran a test retrieving a sorted subset of documents (eg. the first 10) from a large collection, and the time taken to retrieve the sorted set depended on the size of the document collection rather than the number of documents being retrieved. This indicates to me that Realm is sorting the whole collection of documents when a query is made rather than storing the data sorted. Could you update your answer? I can also post the code I ran to test this if you would prefer.

Comment: @pdiffley I am not sure I understand; what does *retrieve a sorted set* mean in terms of using a Realm .filter or .sort? Also what does *sorting the whole collection of documents when a query is made* mean? A sort and a filter are two separate and distinct things so you can't actually sort a collection with a "query". You can define a sort *and/or* you can define a filter and the Results will adhere to what was defined. I am happy to update the answer with more info, can you update your question with the code you're referring to. I'll take a look and ensure my answer addresses the question.

Comment: I updated the question to be more specific. I am less concerned about the laziness of the document retrieval and more concerned about how long retrieving a small number of sorted documents will take.

Comment: @pdiffley The testing code in your question doesn't have anything to do with retrieving a small number of documents from Realm. I think that's where the confusion is. If you want to test how long it takes load objects from Realm, you would add an observer to a results object, then retrieve the results and when the observer fires, then it's done. Compare the two times. I think you'll be surprised; it's really fast.

Comment: The only part of the code that is timed is the portion that reads 10 values from the result set, so the test does show the time taken to retrieve a small number of documents. All document writing and memory allocation was taken care of in advance, so that is not a factor in the test.

Comment: @pdiffley Updated the question with specific details and example code following the Edit. I hope that helps.